# Concatenating and splitting json files in a 1 level deep folder structure

Tags: batch-file, split, windows-10, concatenation

I'm working on a translation project the content of which is in a one level deep folder structure in JSON files.
Essentialy it looks like this

```
\folder1
    file1.json
    file2.json
    ...
\folder2
    file3.json
    file4.json
    ...
```

I need some automated way to:

- Merge these into a single file, preferebly one that contains the original file name and folder as the first line of each file's content
  e.g.:

```
    \folder1\file1.json
    <file1 content>

    \folder1\file2.json
    <file2 content>

    \folder2\file3.json
    <file3 content>

    \folder2\file4.json
    <file4 content>
```

- Split the merged file and re-create the original folder structure.

I'm using Windows10.

Comment: Tip: this question is going to be downvoted and maybe closed because you don't seem to have tried anything by yourself. Make some research and then come back with concrete doubts you may have.

Comment: @Novbert This might help. You can append different files using the `COPY` utility by specifying several files as source. For instance, `copy \V \Y C:\File1+C:\File2 C:\Target\Folder\result` will copy to an unique new file (result) with File1 and File2 appended in someway.

Comment: This could work: `(@for /D %%J in ("*") do @for %%I in ("%%~J\*.json") do @((echo/%%~I) & type "%%~I")) > "merged.json"`

Comment: The above comment only covers the merging part. Anyway, since you did not show any own efforts, your question is too broad and therefore off-topic, so please take the [tour] and read these help articles: [ask], [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Merging all JSON files found in the first directory level downwards from the current working directory:

```
@echo off
rem // Write all output to a single file:
> "merged.json" (
    rem // Walk through the first directory level:
    for /D %%J in ("*") do (
        rem // Walk through all files per directory:
        for %%I in ("%%~J\*.json") do (
            rem // Return relative path to current file preceded by `.\`:
            echo .\%%~I
            rem // Return content of current file:
            type "%%~I"
            rem // Return blank line:
            echo/
        )
    )
)
```

In the merged JSON file, every relative source file path becomes preceded by `.\`.

---

Splitting into JSON files in the first directory level downwards from the current working directory (note that there is no initial directory/file clean-up done):

```
@echo off
rem // Clear buffer holding relative path of current file:
set "FILE="
rem // Read merged file line by line:
for /F "usebackq delims= eol=#" %%K in ("merged.json") do (
    rem // Store current line text:
    set "LINE=%%K"
    rem /* Enable delayed expansion in order to become able to
    rem    write and read the same variable within the loop: */
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    rem // Check whether current line begins with `.\`:
    if "!LINE:~,2!"==".\" (
        rem // Current line begins with `.\`, so treat as relative file path:
        endlocal
        rem // Create first directory level:
        2> nul md "%%K\.."
        rem // Create empty file to append to:
        > "%%K" rem/
        rem // Store resolved relative file path for later use:
        set "FILE=%%K"
    ) else (
        rem // No leading `.\` found, hence append current line to recent file:
        >> "!FILE!" echo/!LINE!
        endlocal
    )
)
```

The key is to treat all lines beginning with `.\` as relative paths to the individual source files.

Answer (score 0):

This might help,

```
for /r %I IN (*) DO echo.&echo %I>>%I
```

Then copy all files into a single destination using `copy` utility,

```
copy /Y /V c:\folder1\file1.json+c:\folder2\file2.json c:\target\destination\result.json
```